# Metric Space induced by Pseudometric.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, metric-spaces

I am getting confused proving this, mainly, because of how the equivalence relation is defined. Moreover, it is defined as $x \sim y$ if $d(x,y) = 0$.

My question is, does this mean if $d(x,y) = 0$ then $x \sim y$. I feel like this is more a logic question.

Comment: Yes, if $d(x,y) = 0$ then you define $x \sim y$. If $d(x,y) \ne 0$, then $x \not \sim y$.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks!

Comment: Since it is a definition, the if should be if and only if.  So x and y are related  if and only if $ d(x,y)=0$

Comment: Definitions are, sadly, very often phrased using "if" when they mean "if and only if". It is what it is.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks!